# Unable to print LinkedHasMap in Java due to ClassCastException while key is correct

Tags: java, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I am testing REST api. Below is my JSON response.

```
[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Chattagram"
}, {
  "id" : 2,
  "name" : "Rajshahi"
}, {
  "id" : 3,
  "name" : "Khulna"
}, {
  "id" : 4,
  "name" : "Barisal"
}, {
  "id" : 5,
  "name" : "Sylhet"
}, {
  "id" : 6,
  "name" : "Dhaka"
}, {
  "id" : 7,
  "name" : "Rangpur"
}, {
  "id" : 8,
  "name" : "Mymensingh"
} ]
```

I have converted the list into a List of HashMap. I am able to access the `name` field but when trying to get the `id`, below exception is happening. I am not understanding why this exception, cause the key is correct. I have given the debug console image, can any one tell me what is the issue and how i can access the `id`?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

**Source Code :**

```
@Test
    public void getEmployees() throws IOException {
        final String uri = "http://localhost:8080/public/geocode/divisions";

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
        restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
        System.out.println(result);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list = mapper.readValue(result, List.class);
        System.out.println(list.get(0));//--------------out put : {id=1, name=Chattagram}
        Map<String, String> m = list.get(0);
        System.out.println("id : " + m.get("id"));     //------------problem line
        System.out.println("Name : " + m.get("name")); //------------working fine
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

After setting a break point in the problem line, debug variables : 
[image: Debug Output]

Comment: `Map<String, String>`, but the value of `id` is `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
System.out.println("id : " + Integer.toString(m.get("id"));
```